# Spring WebSocket Connecting with SockJS to a different domain

Tags: spring, websocket, http-status-code-403, sockjs

WebSockets in Spring is a rather new topic that I;m tiring to find a bit more.

My problem is with connecting to a service from a different domain, I'm working on with Lineman building the front-end side and Spring Boot when doing the back-end side, with that I have these apps on two different ports : 8000 and 8080 on localhost.

I had issues with the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header but I have resolved it by adding a filter on the server side which added the allowed origin to the header. After this I started to get the following error on connection:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/socket/info 403 (Forbidden)
AbstractXHRObject._start @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:807
(anonymous function) @sockjs-0.3.4.js:841
```

I don't have Spring Security in the project so this is not an authorization issue, the error points to sockJS :
that.xhr.send(payload); - where payload is never defined.I tried but couldn't find the root of the call where is may began.

I was thinking if I need to add some additional information to either SockJS and Stomp when setting the connection, but there is not much of examples and notes in both wiki pages of this tools.

Bellow you will find the connection JS code.

```
var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/socket");
client = Stomp.over(socket);

client.connect({'login': BoatsGame.userName,
                    'passcode': 'guest'},
            function (frame) {
....

The Server Side has a MessageBroker configured :    


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MessageBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Bean
public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
     ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
     container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8192);
     container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8192);
     return container;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
     //config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic");
     config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic","/user");
     config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/BoatBattleGame");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket").withSockJS();
}
}
```

I Also tried setting up a MessageHandler as it has the option to set OriginAllowe when configuring, but I'm not sure how it is connected to the broker.

Last think, this setup works correctly when running on one port.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Jax's answer was correct :)

The registerStompEndpoints method gives us the opportunity to set the Allowed Origins.
We need to add it before the "withSockJs()" option.

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/BO/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

Comment: Does this also connection from mobile clients apart from sockjs?

Answer (score 7):

To anyone getting to this ticket because of the 403 Forbidden answer when trying to connect through a SockJsClient to a different domain:

The problem arises when trying to make a GET to the /info Url, as part of the handshaking. The response actually returns a 200 via WGET as well as via browser. Only through SockJsClient it doesn't work.

After trying different solutions, the only one that really fixed the issue is to write a class that implements Transport and InfoReceiver. In this way the developer can directly handle this part of the handshake.
Basically you make the work in the executeInfoRequest() method:

```
@Override
public String executeInfoRequest(URI infoUrl, HttpHeaders headers) {
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(infoUrl); // eventually add headers here
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        List<String> responseOutput = IOUtils.readLines(response.getEntity().getContent());

        return responseOutput.get(0);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I defined TransportType.XHR as transport type.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had to add these configuarations to get SockJS / STOM to work with CORS:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600)
                .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type", "Origin", 
"Authorization", "X-Auth-Token")
                .exposedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! It pointed me in the right direction, I missed this part in my application :-)

Comment: I added a class like above, and it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Solved it for me. Missing link for me was that I didn't expect Spring to reuse the main CORS configuration, the one most people use for HTTP(S) endpoints, for its WebSockets. Apparently it does.

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution by creating a Filter

```
package com.diool.notif.config;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("Initilisation du Middleware");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest requestToUse = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse responseToUse = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;

        responseToUse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",requestToUse.getHeader("Origin"));
        filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse,responseToUse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: where did u place it? You had to do more changes but adding this class?

Comment: i put it inside the "config" folder on my package