# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: java, spring, websocket, cors, spring-websocket

I have implemented **WebSockets** with **Spring Boot Application** and have the below error message when trying to test the ws connection with the chrome extension '**Smart websocket client**'. 
However, I have no problem when run the Spring Boot Application locally.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.X.XYZ:8080/test' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

The only difference which I see is in the Request headers:

In the one it works - Origin:http://192.168.X.XYZ:8080

In the one it does not work - Origin:chrome-extension://omalebghpgejjiaoknljcfmglgbpocdp

What I did in the **WebSocketConfig** class is below:

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/test").setAllowedOrigins("http://192.168.X.XYZ:8080");
}
```

and still does **not** work.

Could you please advise what the reason for that error might be and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502943/spring-websocket-connecting-with-sockjs-to-a-different-domain

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to configure your `"chrome-extension://..."`  origin as an allowed origin or even `"*"`, otherwise it's rejected by the server.

Comment: setAllowedOrigins("*"); fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On update to spring boot 2.4, it also requires:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on the config class.