# websocket_handshake_failed on GCP Cloud http load balancer with 403 response

Tags: google-app-engine, websocket, gcp-load-balancer

We are getting thousands of `websocket_handshake_failed` on our GCP load balancer.
Our Environment is: App Engine Flex environment with auto-scale + Postgress cloud SQL
we have a chat SaaS application so we use sockets.
on the logging, I see +1000 `websocket_handshake_failed` each hour,

[image]

below is the sample of the log of a single error:

```
    {
insertId: "1yr7yf8g129xnqm"
jsonPayload: {2}
httpRequest: {
requestMethod: "GET"
requestUrl: "https://platform.businesschat.io/socket/websocket?auth_token=SFMyNTY.g2gDdAAAAAFkAAd1c2VyX2lkYR5uBgBpppTkeAFiAAFRgA.KRJF8oZWOOtsOS0aqNUzf8OJgip-znonz31WSPGwUlQ&vsn=2.0.0"
requestSize: "2382"
status: 403
responseSize: "231"
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
remoteIp: "188.54.82.167"
serverIp: "10.156.0.30"
}
resource: {
type: "http_load_balancer"
labels: {
target_proxy_name: ""
url_map_name: ""
project_id: "businesschat-platform"
forwarding_rule_name: ""
backend_service_name: "aef-default-20210418t185059-bs"
zone: "global"
}
}
timestamp: "2021-04-19T10:05:16.050343Z"
severity: "WARNING"
logName: "projects/businesschat-platform/logs/requests"
trace: "projects/businesschat-platform/traces/2205a954ba0c5d518574a6b00316fa92"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-04-19T10:05:17.924136122Z"
spanId: "692567857ac6b22b"
}
```

on the front end, Am getting a sample `connection: close error`, not sure if that is related:
[image]

Comment: I understand you are using App Engine Flex, but are you using Java or maybe Spring Boot? This usually happens when you haven't set your allowed origins correctly as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627017/error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-403)

Comment: Is your service account authorized to be used by App Engine Flex ?