# Problem of connection between front and back with WebSocket

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, websocket

I have a project in a vpn and I try to create a chat with a socket using WebSocket. This is the controller:

```
    @MessageMapping("/chat.send")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage sendMessage (@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage){
    return chatMessage;
}

@MessageMapping("/chat.newUser")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage newUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                           SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    // Add username in web socket session
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
    return chatMessage;
}
```

This is the listener:

```
       private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations sendingOperations;

@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketConnectListener (final SessionConnectedEvent event){
    LOGGER.info("Se creo una nueva conexion chat");
    /*final StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    final String username = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("username");

    final ChatMessage chatMessage = ChatMessage.builder()
            .type(MessageType.CONNECT)
            .sender(username)
            .build();

    sendingOperations.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);*/
}

@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener (final SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    final StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    final String username = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("username");

    final ChatMessage chatMessage = ChatMessage.builder()
            .type(MessageType.DISCONNECT)
            .sender(username)
            .build();

    sendingOperations.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
}
```

and this one the config:

```
        @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); //deberia cambiarse por el enableStompBroker
/*
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
                .setRelayHost("localhost")
                .setRelayPort(61613)
                .setClientLogin("guest")
                .setClientPasscode("guest");
*/
    }

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
}
```

the parts commented on I left them like that because I was looking at how to solve the issue.

Now, the client connects by vpn using angle and socketjs. This is the code in angular

```
      export class WebSocketAPIService {

  private webSocketEndPoint: string = environment.baseurl + '/chat.newUser';
  private topic = '/topic/public';
  private stompClient: Stomp.Client;
  public mensajeRecibidoEmitter: EventEmitter<Message> = new EventEmitter<Message>();

  constructor() { }

  public _connect(): void {
    console.log('Initialize WebSocket Connection');
    const ws = new SockJS(this.webSocketEndPoint);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);

    this.stompClient.connect({}, (frame: Frame) => {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(this.topic, (sdkEvent: Message) => {
        this.onMessageReceived(sdkEvent);
      });
      // _this.stompClient.reconnect_delay = 2000;
    }, (err) => this.errorCallBack(err));
  }

  public _disconnect(): void {
    if (this.stompClient !== null) {
      this.stompClient.disconnect(() => {
        console.log('Disconnected');

      });
    }
  }

  // on error, schedule a reconnection attempt
  errorCallBack(error) {
    console.log('errorCallBack -> ' + error);
    setTimeout(() => {
      // this._connect();
      console.log(' trying reconnect...');
    }, 5000);
  }

  _send(message) {
    console.log('calling logout api via web socket');
    this.stompClient.send('/app/hello', {}, JSON.stringify(message));
  }

  onMessageReceived(message: Message): void {
    console.log('Message Recieved from Server :: ' + message);
    // this.appComponent.handleMessage(JSON.stringify(message.body));
    this.mensajeRecibidoEmitter.emit(message);
  }
}
```

and throw this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.100.71:8080/dpo_backend_dev/chat.newUser/info?t=1603389915235' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I don't know how to solve it since I'm learning to use webSocket but for some reason I only listen to what happens in localhosty not connecting between vpn. Any help?

Comment: I believe it is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502943/spring-websocket-connecting-with-sockjs-to-a-different-domain

Comment: I tried what I said and it didn't work, it even keeps jumping to the same mistakes. I can't get him to make the connection directly.

Comment: the errors tells about CORS is not configured for sure

Comment: now saids: "JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String", but the endpoints i put it as public. So don't need the token.

Comment: do you send invalid token from your FE? you can check this in the devtools i guess